# Free a double pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, free, double-pointer

I have two functions to create arrays.

```
double *Array1D (int nx, int dsize) {
  double *v;
  v = calloc(nx, dsize);
  return v;
}

double **Array2D (int ny, int nx, int dsize) {
  double **v; int j;
  for (j = 0; j < ny; j++)
    v[j] = Array1D(nx, dsize);
  return v;
}

int i, j;
pn = Array2D (ny, nx, sizeof(double));
for (j = 0; j < ny; j++)
  for (i = 0; i < nx; i++)
    pn[j][i] = 1.0 + (i + j * nx) * 1.0;

for (i = 0; i < ny; i++)
  free(pn[i]);
free(pn);
```

The array elements get initialized properly, but freeing them creates a segmentation fault.

Error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./array_test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff00d42a4f ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Why do you pass in `dsize`, when `sizeof (double)` is constant? It's like it's trying to be general, but still uses `double *` internally. Very confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double **Array2D (int ny, int nx, int dsize)
{
  double **v; int j;
  for (j=0; j<ny; j++) v[j] = Array1D(nx, dsize);
```

`v` object is never initialized in your function.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain your downvote and if you think the problem is elsewhere please elaborate.

Comment: Not the downvoter (in fact, I'm one of the upvoters), but while you specify what the problem is, you never specify how to fix it (i.e., put either a `malloc` or `calloc` call before the loop).

Comment: @wolfPack88 This is deliberate. I point where the problem is (and so answer the question on what does trigger the segfault) and now it is up to the OP to figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You never allocate memory for your 2d array. You need a line `v = malloc(sizeof(double *) * ny);` right before your `for` loop in `double **Array2D(int ny, int nx, int dsize);`

Answer (score 3):

The order of allocation is

```
v = malloc(sizeof(double *) * ny);
for (j=0; j<ny; j++) v[j] = Array1D(nx, dsize);
```

The order of freeing is

```
for (j=0; j<ny; j++)
free(v[j]);

free(v);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double **Array2D (int ny, int nx, int dsize) {
    double **v; int j;
    for (j=0; j<ny; j++) v[j] = Array1D(nx, dsize);
    return v;
}
```

You forgot to allocate `*v`.